# TypeError: Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-services

How can i solve this type of error 
This is my Service file

```
summaryData(data):Observable <SummaryReport>{
    debugger;
    let headers = new HttpHeaders({'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
    return this.http.post<SummaryReport>(this.baseurl,data,{headers:headers})
  }
```

This is my component

```
  GetSummaryData(){
    debugger;
    console.log(this.auctionID);
    this.httpService.summaryData(this.auctionID).subscribe(
      data=>this._summaryReport, error=>alert(error))
  }
```

Comment: what and where is the error? (give stack-trace)

Comment: The error is most likely due to `this.baseurl`, where do you declare it?

Comment: Please utilize your (browser&#39;s) breakpoints while debugging the code. This kind of error is the result of undefined variable/expected string that you attempt to turn into lower case